# Custome attribue in magento having different values for two products types

Tags: magento, custom-attributes

In Magento is it possible to have a custom attribute say "Type" with different values for each prodcut type for example Shoes, and Chairs?

Here is an example to explain - (Categories can be any, this is just example)
I have products shoes, and shirts , 2 different categories for both.
Now shoes can have style like "Sports","Casual","Formal" where as Chairs can have style like "Rocking","Computer Chair","Classic" and so on.

Can I have one custom attribute Type, and have different values for both the products in drop-down?

Answer (score 0):

Magento has attribute sets for that http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/how-do-i-create-an-attribute-set